# override html.validationmessageFor error message

Tags: c#, html-helper, jquery-validation-engine

is there a way for me to override the message from `Html.ValidationMessageFor`.
So when it is activated, it will display the new message ?

I have tried to add this to my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "validation error message goes here")]
public decimal Average { get; set; }
```

but that wont work.

and if i add the message to the html it self, it will display it always on page load:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Average, "validation error message goes here", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I need to change the error message provided for my language (danish) instead of just the model name which is in english.

Comment: Not clear what you asking, or why your saying `[Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]` does not work. But you can use resource files to localize your error messages - refer [this blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/07/localizing-aspnetmvc-validation.aspx/) for an example

Comment: i found the solution, i just removed "validation error message goes here" from html.validationmessagefor, and typed null instead. Then it didn't override the required validation message in my model.